# Where is the source code for the Mozilla / Firefox Input Dashboard?

Tags: firefox, open-source

Where can I find the source code for the Mozilla / Firefox Input Dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you require : https://github.com/fwenzel/reporter ?
Please excuse because I'm not sure.

Comment: @Hosam Aly : Welcome :-)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I am one of the Firefox Input developers.